# Efficient way to translate a char* to an enum value

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

In **C**, I can use the preprocessor to convert a `enum` to its string equivalent.

But is there any clever trick to convert a `char*` to a `enum`.

I can use an if statement and a `strcmp` for each string and return equivalent `enum` but is there a more elegant way?

Comment: I don't think there's any clever tricks you can do here that will be as efficient as writing a parser for you enum.

Comment: @Jeff Mercado: What about my answer? It's nearly just as efficient as a hand-written parser but it can be used on any enum made with `CREATEENUM`.

Comment: @night: That certainly works, no argument there.  But in terms of efficiency in time and space, it doesn't beat a tailor-made enum parser.  First you'd need space to store the string representations of the values (not so bad).  Then you'd need to compare the input string to all the string representations for potentially all values of the enum (can be bad).  A parser (DFA) can avoid all that overhead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please, don't do such hackery. You have **almost certainly** a design flaw.

---

EDIT: If you really **must** do this for some reason I hacked together this. The example should also show it's usage:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

/*** BEGIN HACK ***/

#define CREATEENUM(name, first, ...) \
    typedef enum { first = 0, __VA_ARGS__ } name; \
    char name##_s[] = #first ", " #__VA_ARGS__;
#define TOSTR(x) #x
#define TOENUM(name, x) ((name) _toenum(name##_s, x))

long _toenum(char *enum_s, const char *x) {
    long i = 0;
    size_t len = strlen(enum_s);

    char *copy = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char) * (len + 1));
    strncpy(copy, enum_s, len);
    copy[len] = '\0';

    char *saveptr = NULL;
    char *s = strtok_r(copy, ", ", &saveptr);
    do {
        if (strcmp(s, x) == 0) {
            free(copy);
            return i;
        }
        i++;
    } while((s = strtok_r(NULL, ", ", &saveptr)) != NULL);

    free(copy);
    return -1;
}

/*** END HACK ***/

// create enum with the name "super"
CREATEENUM(super,
    COOL,
    AWESOME,
    UBER,
    JON_SKEET
)

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    printf("%d\n", TOENUM(super, "JON_SKEET")); // 3
    printf("%d\n", TOENUM(super, "EXTREME")); // -1 (not found)
    printf("%d\n", TOENUM(super, "COOL")); // 0

    printf("%s\n", TOSTR(AWESOME)); // AWESOME
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @John Zwinck: I mean if you are forced to do things like this your code most likely doesn't have a good structure.

Comment: I don't know, it's C after all, it's not like C's enums are very rich or useful out of the box.  The OP's problem seems, if anything, rather common.

Comment: This is probably the best answer.  Just trying to save time in an earlier stage has caused this issue.

Answer (score 2):

You could create a structure with the enum and char* values and search through them for each conversion. Might be handy if you have a lot of enum types. Based on [this thread](http://www.programmersheaven.com/mb/CandCPP/287656/287656/converting-from-char---to-enum-type/).

```
enum colors {
  unknown = 0,
  red,
  blue,
  black,
  yellow
};

struct enumtypes
{
   colors color;
   char* str;
};

struct enumtypes array[] = {
  {red,"red"},
  {blue,"blue"}
  // etc for each enum type  
};

// function to convert string to enum type
colors cvt(const char* str)
{
   const int sz = sizeof(array) / sizeof(array[0]);

   for(int i = 0; i < sz; i++)
   {
       if(strcmp(array[i].str, str) == 0)
          return array[i].color;
   }
   return unknown;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I suspect what you really want is not enums, but a way to map an integer to a string and back. For example, you might be representing months, and use integers to allow easy comparisons ("is this date before that date"), and the string to allow more human-friendly representation.

(I had to guess this, since your question did not explain what you're actually trying to solve.)

If you abandon enums, you can write a little helper library that solves this problem in a generic way. A really simple way to implement the mapping would be to use a simple array of strings, and use the index in the array as the integer:

```
#include <string.h>

/* Find string in mapping. Return -1 if not found. */
int map_string_to_int(char *map[], int count, char *string)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
        if (strcmp(map[i], string) == 0)
            return i;
    }
    return -1;
}

/* Map int to string. Return NULL if not found. */
char *map_int_to_string(char *map[], int count, int i)
{
    if (i < 0 || i >= count)
        return NULL;
    return map[i];
}

/* Add new string to mapping. Return its unique id. Return existing id if
   string was in mapping already. Caller is responsible to make sure 
   there's room. Caller is responsible for making sure string does not
   get de-allocated. */
int map_add(char *map[], int *count, char *string)
{
    int i;

    i = map_string_to_int(map, *count, string);
    if (i == -1) {
        i = *count;
        map[i] = string;
        ++(*count);
    }
    return i;
}


/* A main program for testing, not actually part of the library. */

#include <stdio.h>

#define N 1024
int main(void)
{
    char *map[N];
    int count;

    map_add(map, &count, "Monday");
    map_add(map, &count, "Tuesday");
    map_add(map, &count, "Thursday");
    map_add(map, &count, "Wednesday");
    map_add(map, &count, "Friday");
    map_add(map, &count, "Sunday");
    map_add(map, &count, "Saturday");

    for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i)
        printf("[%d] = %s\n", i, map_int_to_string(map, count, i));

    printf("Monday is %d\n", map_string_to_int(map, count, "Monday"));

    return 0;
}
```

More efficient ways of doing this are possible. Before you start working on them, remember to measure how much impact this mapping actually has on your runtime.

- Have a second array, which keeps the strings sorted, and look for strings using
  binary search. The first table remains, so that it's still fast to map an integer
  to a string.
- Use a hash table for the second array.
- Ditch the first array completely, and use the hash values as the integers, if you
  can find a hash function that has no collisions for your particular data. This should
  be perfectly feasible if you were going to be using enums anyway, since then the
  set of values is fixed at compile time. (You still need the hash table for reverse
  mapping: from integer to string.)

For example, if your values represent weekdays, using the first two characters as the hash function is entirely sufficient. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_hashing for pointers to some related information on constructing such hash functions in the general case.

Answer (score 0):

If you can trust the `char*` and if it's amenable to simple calculations, try this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

enum Weekdays {
      Sun = 'S' + 'u' + 'n',
      Mon = 'M' + 'o' + 'n',
      Tue = 'T' + 'u' + 'e',
      Wed = 'W' + 'e' + 'd',
      Thu = 'T' + 'h' + 'u',
      Fri = 'F' + 'r' + 'i',
      Sat = 'S' + 'a' + 't'
};

int main(void) {
  char tmp[10];
  printf("Enter day of the week: ");
  fflush(stdout);
  if (fgets(tmp, sizeof tmp, stdin)) {

    enum Weekdays enumvalue =
          tmp[0] + tmp[1] + tmp[2];

    switch (enumvalue) {
      default:    printf("Ohoh\n"); break;
      case Sun:   printf("Sun: %d\n", Sun); break;
      case Mon:   printf("Mon: %d\n", Mon); break;
      case Tue:   printf("Tue: %d\n", Tue); break;
      case Wed:   printf("Wed: %d\n", Wed); break;
      case Thu:   printf("Thu: %d\n", Thu); break;
      case Fri:   printf("Fri: %d\n", Fri); break;
      case Sat:   printf("Sat: %d\n", Sat); break;
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not terribly clever but if your strings are few and very short (4 bytes or something that fits in an integer type) you can recast them as integers and use in switch and the like. Hackery for sure but sometimes that may give you what you want.

Answer (score 0):

There aren't any "clever" ways to do this *efficiently* AFAIK.  Just write a simple parser for your particular enum and be done with it.  Of course there's the limitation that this will only apply for a single enum and will not work for all enums in general.  C doesn't have mechanisms in place to do this like other languages, it is too low level.

For the heck of it, here's an example of a hand-written "classical" DFA to parse this `MyEnum`:

```
typedef enum
{
    MyEnum_foo,
    MyEnum_bar,
    MyEnum_baz,
} MyEnum;

/**
 * M -> y -> E -> n -> u -> m -> _ -> f -> o -> o
 *                                 -> b -> a -> r
 *                                           -> z
 */

MyEnum parse_MyEnum(const char *str)
{
    int state = 0;
    MyEnum result;
    if (str == 0) { /* handle null pointer error */ }
    for ( ; ; )
    {
        char c = *str++;
        switch (state)  /* case sensitive parse */
        {
        case 0:
            /* we could jump to state 7 with the
               appropriate check here but I won't :) */
            switch (c)
            {
            case 'M': state = 1; break;
            default: goto error_state;
            }
            break;
        case 1:     /* M */
            switch (c)
            {
            case 'y': state = 2; break;
            default: goto error_state;
            }
            break;
        case 2:     /* My */
            switch (c)
            {
            case 'E': state = 3; break;
            default: goto error_state;
            }
            break;
        case 3:     /* MyE */
            switch (c)
            {
            case 'n': state = 4; break;
            default: goto error_state;
            }
            break;
        case 4:     /* MyEn */
            switch (c)
            {
            case 'u': state = 5; break;
            default: goto error_state;
            }
            break;
        case 5:     /* MyEnu */
            switch (c)
            {
            case 'm': state = 6; break;
            default: goto error_state;
            }
            break;
        case 6:     /* MyEnum */
            switch (c)
            {
            case '_': state = 7; break;
            default: goto error_state;
            }
            break;
        case 7:     /* MyEnum_ */
            switch (c)
            {
            case 'f': state = 8; break;
            case 'b': state = 11; break;
            default: goto error_state;
            }
            break;
        case 8:     /* MyEnum_f */
            switch (c)
            {
            case 'o': state = 9; break;
            default: goto error_state;
            }
            break;
        case 9:     /* MyEnum_fo */
            switch (c)
            {
            case 'o': state = 10; break;
            default: goto error_state;
            }
            break;
        case 10:    /* MyEnum_foo */
            switch (c)
            {
            case '\0': result = MyEnum_foo; goto accept_state;
            default: goto error_state;
            }
            break;
        case 11:    /* MyEnum_b */
            switch (c)
            {
            case 'a': state = 12; break;
            default: goto error_state;
            }
            break;
        case 12:    /* MyEnum_ba */
            switch (c)
            {
            case 'r': state = 13; break;
            case 'z': state = 14; break;
            default: goto error_state;
            }
            break;
        case 13:    /* MyEnum_bar */
            switch (c)
            {
            case '\0': result = MyEnum_bar; goto accept_state;
            default: goto error_state;
            }
            break;
        case 14:    /* MyEnum_baz */
            switch (c)
            {
            case '\0': result = MyEnum_baz; goto accept_state;
            default: goto error_state;
            }
            break;
        default:
            /* we shouldn't be here */
            assert(0);
        }
    }
error_state:
    /* handle error */
    result = (MyEnum)-1;
accept_state:
    return result;
}
```